# Drupal and Git workflow using Acquia cloud

Tags: 8, workflows, version-control, acquia-dev-desktop

Currently i have my central repo (origin repo) on a Bonobo Git Server.

I have followed [those steps](https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/manage/code/github) to use Acquia Cloud with a remote repository.

On my [Acquia cloud repo](http://mvdbdcg7vgrppb.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/) i installed Drupal 8.

- also i already cloned my origin repo (Bonobo Git Server) locally to my computer.

Now i think the best workflow is to clone the Acquia Cloud repo locally isn’t it? With the whole Drupal 8 core and all files from the Drupal 8 installation.

So after that i can add contributed modules and themes to my local repo and commit and push them to my origin repo (Bonobo Git Server) and the Acquia Cloud repo?

1. Is this the a correct workflow? And how do i get all the Drupal 8
   files from Acquia Cloud to my local repo?
2. i have read also something about *'Translating your root directory with git subtree'* in [this article](https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/manage/code/github). Is this correct and what do i have to do exactly regarding my workflow
3. Is it advisable to use Acquia dev desktop also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Acquia

This library article you linked to originates from an [blog post](https://dev.acquia.com/blog/using-github-acquia-cloud) that was written 4 years ago to answer questions about deploying from Jenkins build servers, private Github repos, etc. There's nothing specific to Acquia Cloud per se and it's rather a Git strategy you need to come up with for your development needs.

Is the Bonobo Git Server going to be the 'origin' going forward?

- If yes, then simply add the Acquia Cloud as a new remote (e.g. 'ac').
  Git allows you to push to different remotes without any issue.
- If not, then you should make Acquia Cloud the 'origin' and Bonobo a
  regular remote (probably easier).

Since Git is decentralized, you 'own' the repo at any point in time and the main reason for keeping a remote is if you have a continuous integration system you need to pass your codebase through before you deploy code to Acquia Cloud. Another good reason is if you have a preferred Git workflow (think Github pull requests for instance) you wish to continue working with. But if you simply want to mirror your Acquia Cloud repo to (for instance) back it up, then I'd argue to just keep the Acquia Cloud repo and simplify your workflow.

The idea to keep in mind is you need only **one** checkout of your codebase. Having several remotes allows you to handle where to push to as described in the article.

Comment: thanks a lot. What do you mean exactly with 'Is the Bonobo Git Server going to be the 'origin' going forward?' and the Bonobo server is setup by my client because he has also commit code to it. I think i want to use Acquia cloud to have a staging environment which is visible for everyone and maybe we want to host the live website at Acquia to benefit of stage > production environment. Is that the best setup of workflow?

Comment: So the only fixed values are: the Bonobo Git Server (setup by my client), where my client also can commit code and i need a staging environment and a live environment.

Comment: sorry but do you have an answer on above, so i can continue setup my workflow and use Acquia Cloud. I installed [Drupal 8](http://mvdbdcg7vgrppb.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/) on Acquia Cloud already. How do i have to continue? How do i get this Drupal 8 core code in my local repo and the Bonobo server? And from that point i can add contributed modules and themes to my local repo isn't it?

Comment: I understand using the Bonobo server isn't really a preference but a requirement from your client. In that case, it needs to stay the default / preferred remote Git server and you could push both to it and to Acquia Cloud by having several git remotes (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes). This workflow is quite typical. You can use Dev to mirror the Bonobo (e.g. with branch master), then push to Stage for QA (creates a git tag) or have another branch, and finally push to Prod (creates a new tag) for the live site.

Comment: **1)** what should you suggest and what should be your preferred workflow/best workflow? Show me also your workflow without the Bonobo server. **2)** If i keep my current workflow (with Bonobo server and Acquia Cloud like i now have, how do i somehow merge Drupal 8 core files from Acquia Cloud to my local repo?

Comment: 1) I recommend the workflow I've detailed above: keep Bonobo and Acquia in synch, then use the dev to stage to prod workflow on Acquia Cloud (https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/manage) 2) You don't really 'merge' per se, you just git pull from Acquia Cloud to your local repo or git push to Acquia Cloud from your local repo. There's nothing specific to Acquia here, it's just how git works.

Comment: ok i will continue at this workflow. To avoid mistakes and have a good setup: how do i continue now, what is my first step if i want to be able to add themes and modules? If i am wright, i first add the themes and modules to my local repo? But then somehow i need all Drupal 8 core files (from Acquia Cloud) in my local repo? How do i have to do this? Or do i mis something?

Comment: You first need to make sure you have your SSH access set up (https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/ssh/enable/add-key) and then you can checkout a local copy of your codebase (https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/site/import/archive/code). Then, you can add your themes and modules locally and (git) push your new code to Acquia Cloud. Again, there is nothing here that is specific to Acquia Cloud. It's how git works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ok now i cloned Acquia Cloud repo to my local repo. If i do a `git status` in my local repo, i see `mvdb/` (this is the name in Sites on Aqcuia dashboard). How do i get this directory to the Bonobo git server? They don't sync automatically isn' it?

Comment: Make sure you're not going to overwrite anything on the Bonobo server. If and only if there's nothing you can possibly overwrite, then add a new git remote to your Acquia Cloud local repo: `git remote add bonobo https://path/to/repo.git` - With this you would have 2 origins to push to: Acquia Cloud and the Bonobo server. On the contrary, if you do have a git tree already on the Bonobo, then I'd suggest you either split things up (keep Bonobo and Acquia Cloud separated) or - if those files are relevant to your Acquia Cloud codebase (e.g. theme or custom module) - then merge them under one repo.

Comment: i don't understand what you exactly mean? If i do `git remote` i see 2 remotes: `ac` (Acquia Cloud repo) and `origin` (Bonobo server). The Bonobo server is completely empty (only one `test.txt file`. What do you mean by _'git tree already on the Bonobo'?_. But the files going to be relevant Bonobo and the Acquia Cloud code base. What do i have to do? I'am a bit lost after your last comment..?

Comment: If your Bonobo server is completely empty, then you don't have to worry about anything. Simply remove your `test.txt` file, then `git push origin master` (or any other branch you have) from your local Acquia Cloud repo. Now you can push to both Acquia Cloud and Bonobo, by simply pushing to `ac` or `bonobo`.

Comment: Why do i have to remove test.txt? Or is it just because its a testfile? And do i have to do `git push -u origin master` (-u)? And what is the value of the Bonobo server anyway? Is it better tell my client to skip it? This server isn't really necessary isn't it? Why should we have the Bonobo server (what reason could my client has)?

Comment: Removing test.txt is simply to start clean. It's by no mean a requirement. Also, if the Bonobo server is only here to mirror the Acquia Cloud repo and there's no other purpose (e.g. continuous integration), then yes I'd suggest you remove that unnecessary complexity. This is actually what I suggested previously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36395/discussion-between-mees-frenkel-frank-and-anavarre).